# Laravel 6 collections - Extract a single value from a record

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6

I have the following collection:

```
 $products = $this->productRepository->getByCompanyId(1)->get();


 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#856 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
       0 => App\OrderItemProduct {#824 ▼
         #table: "product"
         ...
         #attributes: array:3 [▼
            "available" => "5"
            "product_name" => "Product X"
            "product_id" => 1
         ]
         ....
      }
    ]
 }
```

I want to get the `available` value for a single record. I try the following which works if a record exists:

```
$available = $products->where('product_id','=', 1)->first()['available'];
```

However it throws an exception `Trying to access array offset on value of type null` if I try to retrieve the `available` value of a record that doesn't exist in the collection e.g trying to get for product_id 17:

```
$available = $products->where('product_id','=', 17)->first()['available'];
```

This was working in laravel v6 and earlier but no longer seems to work in laravel `6.17.1`

Note in laravel `5.5` I was able to use the `value` method as follows but then that started throwing same errors as above in `v 5.7` so I switched to the above method but now that no loger works either in the latest laravel version.

```
`available = $products->where('product_id','=', 17)->value('available');
```

Also when i try `get` why does it always return null even where record exists?

```
`available = $products->where('product_id','=', 1)->get('available');
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: I think i've tracked the issue down. This is happening becuase of I'm using php 7.4. When I downgrade to php 7.2 it works fine.